# css property nested in previous one - sass

Tags: html, css, sass, atom-editor

Does anyone have problem with Sass? I think I did something with Atom and the css line input is nested in the previous one. See image below. I tried return and shift+return and it just not seems to work

[image]

[image]

Comment: How does it look if you just open it Notepad or nano? Maybe edit it there to make it right if it looks messed up then re open in Atom.

Comment: there is an extra tab in between two lines, edited back in would not work. Re-open didnt work either........